# Can' t see data from repository on junit

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-rest

Hi I wanna try to receive data from my repository but I can t retrieve nothing.
I make autowired and on java class in: " src/main" it works
but in the junit test no

I ve tried any method of Jpa repository but I receive always a "null" parameters

Junit Class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
class testClass {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;


    @Autowired
    private ClienteRepository clienteRepository;


    @Test
    public void test() {


       List<ClienteEntity> cliente = clienteRepository.findAll();
        System.out.println(cliente);

    }
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface ClienteRepository extends JpaRepository<ClienteEntity, Integer>{
    ClienteEntity findByEmail(@Param("email") String email);
```

Console
    with the system.out.printl in the  console i have always this output:

```
    Hibernate: select clienteent0_.id as id1_0_, clienteent0_.cap as cap2_0_, clienteent0_.citta as citta3_0_, clienteent0_.cognome as cognome4_0_, clienteent0_.email as email5_0_, clienteent0_.indirizzo as indirizz6_0_, clienteent0_.nome as nome7_0_, clienteent0_.password as password8_0_, clienteent0_.token as token9_0_ from cliente clienteent0_
    []

    a empty list of ClientEntity
```

Comment: Can you try by removing `@DataJpaTest`? Do you understand what this annotation does?

Answer (score 0):

Based on `@DataJpaTest` docs:

> If an embedded database is available on the classpath, it configures
>   one as well

So double-check if there isn't any and follow this doc if needed:

> If, however, you prefer to run tests against a real database you can
>   use the `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase`

As your test may be using an embedded one based on the annotations of your entities and you are testing agains an empty DB.

**Edit**

If you look at the `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase` you can see for what properties the test will be looking at in terms of DB config:

```
@PropertyMapping(value="spring.test.database")
```

Comment: hi, thanks for trying help me
if i want use not a embedded DB? 
 how can connect a real DB with test?
i m trying with the same properties who i use on src/main

Comment: check my upadte

Comment: i resolved with :
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = Replace.NONE)
Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the situation, it may be necessary to check for other settings in the test scope.

In spring boot, if there is an embedded database, it is composed of that database in the test scope.

Comment: In addition, if you want integration testing, it may be wise to use [`@SpringBootTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications).

Comment: He wants to test only the repo level. He does not need the entire web server

Comment: hi, thanks for trying help me if i want use not a embedded DB? how can connect a real DB with test? i m trying with the same properties who i use on src/main

Comment: try `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase`. [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-jpa-test)

Comment: i resolved with :
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = Replace.NONE)
Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Try using this annotations.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {HCSRepositoryContext.class})
```

Comment: hi thanks for trying help me, i ve tried but i have however the same problem
java.lang.nullPointerException
i think can t connect to my DB